# bulk email to two addresses - tokens don't work

Tags: civimail, tokens

We have separate records for students and parents in our database. All student records include both their personal emails (if they offer one) and their parent's email. We would like to send emails to both addresses and have recently set up so we can include both in bulk emails. (Before we had a separate group for parents & students and included both groups in emails).  However the tokens do not work when sending bulk emails to both addresses. I sent an email to notify students of their audition results, but the field was blank when they received it. When sent to students only (using regular email, not bulk email) or to students w/ a CC to the other email address, it worked. Is there a trick to making the tokens work, or is it just too confusing to use tokens for more than one address in the record? Thanks for any help

Wordpress Version 4.9.5
CiviCRM 4.7.31.

Comment: what mysql version are you using & do you have 'search primary only disabled'? - these could affect the results

Comment: @user4278 how could that help?

Comment: @yobc it would help if you could explain which tokens you want to have included in your e-mail.

Comment: It's a custom field token to identify the group assignment. The field works when we send individual emails, including with a CC, but not when we send bulk emails to both addresses in the record..

Answer (score 1):

You could try this extension for tokens & see if it helps
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken